Combine the main script and secondary script into one executable
I would to combine a principal (bash) script Start.sh with another one that is called by the principal into a single script that I will share with the users to execute.
I used this command: shar -M -D -Q -q RA_Test/ | sed '/^exit 0/d' > Easy.sh && echo "RA_Test/Start.sh" >> Easy.sh ; sh Easy.sh , but it didn't work. It shows me this message: No such file or directory for the second script when the principal script reaches the line of calling it.
Could you help me with this?
Thank you.

Why not jst share the folder with all required scripts ? Also is this a one off case or u need it to be automated ? If one off jst copy all contents to the primary script.

The problem is that the second script is called with the establishment of the SSH connection ssh  <user_name>@ source ./Call.sh  , which is why I had to combine the entire set of commands into one script.

It worked for me. I just had to explicitly state that Easy.sh file is in the current folder.
shar -M -D -Q -q RA_Test/ | sed '/^exit 0/d' > Easy.sh && echo "RA_Test/Start.sh" >> Easy.sh ; sh ./Easy.sh

Also, make sure that the Start.sh in the RA_Test folder is executable (chmod +x Start.sh)


I always have the same problem. Yes, the first script executes, but once it gets to the second script, it says the file doesn't exist, even though it's already been combined in Easy.sh

@RACHIDOUBELK : Did you notice the use of ./ pre-pended to Easy.sh. It should work that way. You could also try echo .... >/tmp/Easy.sh ; /tmp/Easy.sh ; /bin/rm /tmp/Easy.sh.  Good luck.
